# How to apply custom color on candlesticks based on OPEN/CLOSE values?

Tags: highcharts, candlestick-chart

I'm working on candlesticks (highStock). Is there any function through which I can change color of individual candlesticks based on Open/close values ? by default it gives blue and white color, i.e. if opening values are greater then closing values then color will be blues , and if closing value is greater then opening values then color will be white. but i want to apply green and red color instead on blue and white. also i want to apply white color if the closing price is same as opening. 
any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in Advance ;)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can find your answer from the below link:

[Highstock Docs for candlestick chart](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/6.0.4/series.candlestick.upColor)

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/plotoptions/candlestick-color/)

Code:

```
plotOptions: {
    candlestick: {
        color: 'red',
        upColor: 'green'
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for this.   I think you want color: 'red', upColor: 'green' of course.